# Firefox inserts escape characters in SVG — XML declaration not well-formed

Tags: html, css, svg, escaping, data-uri

I have CSS code that sets the background of an element to an SVG image, it works fine in Chrome but in Firefox I get escape characters everywhere and my graphics won’t show.

Why is firefox giving me all these `\`?

```css
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\"> <svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Isolation_Mode\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\" width=\"19.636px\" height=\"10.83px\" viewBox=\"0 0 19.636 10.83\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 19.636 10.83\" xml:space=\"preserve\"> <polyline fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#e6e5e1\" stroke-width=\"3\" stroke-linecap=\"round\" stroke-miterlimit=\"10\" points=\"2.232,1.882 9.818,8.741 17.403,1.882 \"/> </svg>")
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding the SVG data as Base64 and using a [Base64 data-URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs)? There are too many characters in such SVG code that syntactically interfere with CSS.

Comment: thank you, we were using base64 encoding in sass, kinda like this:  @return url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ base64_encode($svg));. But sass compile times kept going up and eventually we decided to go libsass instead. Is there a base_encode64() function one could use in libsass? Unfortunately, we can't just statically have everything be base64 since we are generating colors for the elements before encoding.

Answer (score 3):

You are using double quotes for both the url and for the data contained in the URL. The usual thing is to use single quotes for one and double quotes for the other e.g.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version='...
```

or

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="...
```

Firefox is quite right in escaping the inner quotes in your case.

The reason Firefox will not display anything is that the # character is reserved in a URL to indicate [a fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and needs to be escaped as %23 if you're not using it as that. So

```
stroke=\"#e6e5e1\"
```

is invalid. Chrome should reject this but it currently doesn't and therefore does not treat fragment identifiers properly.

Comment: Thank you, that was exhaustive. I was mostly weirded out by the insertion of escape characters. I guess i will have to find a way to get things base64 encoded again.